# Can't Install ROS Indigo on the Raspberry Pi 2 model B(jessie)

Tags: raspberrypi, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm installing ROS Indigo on the Raspberry Pi 2 model B(jessie). I'm following [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi) .But I can't install ROS!!

On 3.2.1 Unavailable Dpendencies, libconsole-bridge-dev of the tutorials, I execute command "`$ apt-get source -b console-bridge'`".Then I get a following error message.

```
    Linking CXX static library libgtest.a
cd /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/external_src/console-bridge-0.3.2/obj-arm-linux-gnueabihf/test && /usr/bin/cmake -P CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
CMake Error: Error in cmake code at
/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/external_src/console-bridge-0.3.2/obj-arm-linux-gnueabihf/test/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake:1:
Parse error.  Expected a command name, got unquoted argument with text "ick]r�
                                                                              ".
CMake Error: Error processing file: CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
test/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/build.make:88: recipe for target 'test/libgtest.a' failed
make[3]: *** [test/libgtest.a] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/external_src/console-bridge-0.3.2/obj-arm-linux-gnueabihf'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:154: recipe for target 'test/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [test/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/external_src/console-bridge-0.3.2/obj-arm-linux-gnueabihf'
Makefile:130: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/external_src/console-bridge-0.3.2/obj-arm-linux-gnueabihf'
dh_auto_build: make -j1 returned exit code 2
debian/rules:7: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build gave error exit status 2
Build command 'cd console-bridge-0.3.2 && dpkg-buildpackage -b -uc' failed.
E: Child process failed
```

I have no idea how I can solve the error. Can you please give me information on that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249603/can%27t-install-ros-indigo-on-the-raspberry-pi-2-model-b(jessie)/) by [NKCT](https://answers.ros.org/users/28432/nkct/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-12-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
Parse error.  Expected a command name, got unquoted argument with text "ick]r�
                                                                              ".
```

This looks like your CMake files have been corrupted. It's not clear why or how that happened during your build. I'd look for filesystem issues.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0